# how do i get selected RadioButtonList and set it in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

**Solved**

I am coding ASP.NET project using C# and store my datas on MYSQL. My problem is i can parse url and can fill KayitAyrinti.aspx 's textboxes, textareas but cant do it for radiobuttonlist.

How can i solve this situation?

This is **KayitAyrinti.aspx;**

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList_ayrintiGorusmeYapilanOkul" runat="server" Width="174px">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Seyrantepe Şube 1" Value="Seyrantepe Şube 1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Seyrantepe Şube 2" Value="Seyrantepe Şube 1"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

**KayitAyrinti.aspx.cs;**

```
using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        RadioButtonList_ayrintiIlgilendigiBolum.SelectedValue = (reader["gorusmeYapilanOkul"].ToString());
    }        
 }
```

Comment: What is the concrete issue? I guess you want to assign the correct parameter value., Then don't use `Value="Seyrantepe Şube 1"` but `Value="1"`.

Answer (score 0):

Have different value for each Radio Button List Item and you can set value like this;

```
var selected = reader["gorusmeYapilanOkul"].ToString();
if(RadioButtonList_ayrintiGorusmeYapilanOkul.Items.FindByValue(selected)!=null)
    RadioButtonList_ayrintiGorusmeYapilanOkul.Items.FindByValue(selected).Selected = true;
```

Answer (score -1):

It was about database charset. Checked MySQL DB and saw this issue.

I add my datas in Turkish but it was saving data in English to MySQL DB. While comparing to values it thinks they are not same so can not selected. I setted same charset to my MYSQL DB and Connection String and it works fine.

Set MySQL Charset utf-8 and set connection string like this;

```
MySqlConnection conn= new MySqlConnection("server=xxx;Database=xxx;Uid=xxx;Pwd=xxx;Charset=utf8");
```